# Calculate average for child objects, not parent

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, batch

The problem is it calculates average for the entire Order_Product__c , I want to calculate average for every product__c separately.

Apex class.

```
public class ProductMaintananceHelper {

  public Decimal avg;


  public void Quantity(){

    AggregateResult[] result= [select ProductESB__c ,avg(Quantity__c)aver from Order_Product__c group by ProductESB__c ];

     for( AggregateResult ar : result){
       avg=(Decimal)ar.get('aver');

        System.debug('avg is '+avg);           
     }
  }
}
```

Batch class.

```
global class BatchapextoUpdateQuantity implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Schedulable {

    global Decimal avg;

    global Database.querylocator start(Database.Batchablecontext bc){
       string  query='select id from Product_maintanance__c';
        return database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<Product_maintanance__c>prolst){

        ProductMaintananceHelper pmh=new ProductMaintananceHelper();
  pmh.Quantity();
   list<Product_maintanance__c> pmlst= new list<Product_maintanance__c>() ;

    for(Product_maintanance__c pmc : prolst){
    pmc.Quantity_del__c= pmh.avg;
        pmlst.add(pmc);
    }
    if(pmlst.size()>0){
        try{
        update pmlst;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception is '+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    }


    global void finish(Database.Batchablecontext bc){

    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        BatchapextoUpdateQuantity ba=new BatchapextoUpdateQuantity();
        Database.executeBatch(ba);
         //tring sch = '0 00 00 * * ?';
     //ystem.schedule ('Batch', sch, new BatchapextoUpdateQuantity());
    }

}
```

---

When I try the method recommended by `@Yaroslav Maksymenko`, the field is not updated.

```
map<id,decimal> prodMap = new map<id,decimal>();    

 for(AggregateResult q : [select ProductESB__c,avg(Quantity__c)aver
    from Order_Product__c  group by ProductESB__c]){

     prodMap.put((Id)q.get('ProductESB__c'),(decimal)q.get('expr0'));
  }      

List<Product_Maintanance__c> prodToUpdate = newList<Product_Maintanance__c>();

  for(Product_Maintanance__c o : [Select Id from Product_Maintanance__c ]){

    decimal avg = prodMap.get(o.Id);
    o.Quantity_del__c=avg;
    prodToUpdate.add(o);
  }
             update prodToUpdate;
            }
```

Comment: Use product__c in group by clause, you are using field api name.

Comment: ProductESB__c is the name of the  product__c field in Order_Product__c object.

Comment: Please do not post edits as answers. You can always **[edit]** your own posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Batch Apex

```
global class BatchapextoUpdateQuantity implements
```

Database.Batchable,Schedulable {

```
global Decimal avg;
global Database.querylocator start(Database.Batchablecontext bc){
   string  query='select id from Product_maintanance__c';
    return database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<Product_maintanance__c>prolst){


ProductMaintananceHelper pmh=new ProductMaintananceHelper();
    pmh.Quantity();
    list<Product_maintanance__c> pmlst= new list<Product_maintanance__c>() ;
    list<Product_maintanance__c> prodlst=[Select Id,Quantity_del__c,Product__c from Product_Maintanance__c];
    Product_maintanance__c obj = new Product_maintanance__c();
    for(Product_maintanance__c pmc : prodlst){
        if(pmc.Product__c == Quanname){
            obj.Id = pmc.Id;
            obj.Product__c = Quanname;
            obj.Quantity_del__c = avg;
            pmlst.add(obj);
        }   
    }
    if(pmlst != null || pmlst.size()>0)
        update pmlst;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for getting average quantity by each separate product is correct.
Just for getting it more nice:

```
for( AggregateResult result : [SELECT ProductESB__c ,avg(Quantity__c)aver FROM Order_Product__c GROUP BY ProductESB__c]) {
    System.debug('product name is ' + result.get('ProductESB__c'));
    System.debug('average quantity for this product is ' + result.get('aver'));
}
```

Comment: when it is executed using batch class it calculates average for the whole records and updates it . i want it to be updated separately based on the product__c

Comment: In this case you need to make avg variable as Map type. Like this: for( AggregateResult ar : result){
       avgMap.put(ar.get('ProductESB__c'), ar.get('aver'));
     }

Answer (score 0):

Apex Class.

```
public class ProductMaintananceHelper {
public Decimal avg;
public Decimal sum;
public Decimal numofelements;
public string Quanname;


public void Quantity(){
AggregateResult[] result= [select ProductESB__r.name,ProductESB__c,count(Quantity__c)totalcount,sum(Quantity__c)sm from Order_Product__c  group by ProductESB__r.name,ProductESB__c];
    for(AggregateResult arr : result){
        numofelements=(Decimal)arr.get('totalcount');
        Quanname=(id)arr.get('ProductESB__c');
        System.debug('num of Quantitiy in '+ Quanname + ' is '+numofelements);

        sum=(Decimal)arr.get('sm');

        avg=sum/numofelements;
        System.debug('avg of '+ Quanname + 'is ' +avg); 
        }
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple versions of your code in answers. Edit your question if you need to provide updates.